# Is there an R function for highlighting the top n bars of a barplot (ggplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am using the following code in order to plot the HUMIDITY per MONTH:

```
ggplot(df_hum, aes(x = month, y = humidity_perc)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = humidity_perc), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme_pubclean()
```

The result is:
[image]

Is there a way to highlight the top 3 months (bars) with the highest humidity with a different color?

Thanks.

Comment: Nope. But you could do `top_months <- dplyr::top_n(df_hum, 3, humidity_perc) %>% pull(month))`, next do `ggplot(..., aes(..., fill = month %in% top_months))` and finally set your desired colors via scale_fill_manual. There is also the `gghighlight` package which may offer some convenience functions out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late and I don't know if this is what you were looking for:

```
# Creating the original data
df_hum <- tibble(month = factor(x = 1:12, levels = 1:12, labels = month.abb),
                 humidity_perc = c(58, 57, 59, 59,
                                   69, 58, 60, 64, 
                                   71, 69, 63, 67))

# Adding an index column which if going to be used as index for highlighting
df_hum$highlight <- "No"

# Change the value only on those which are in the top 3
index <- order(df_hum$humidity_perc, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]

df_hum$highlight[index] <- "Yes"


# Start plotting
ggplot(df_hum, aes(x = month, y = humidity_perc, fill = as.factor(highlight))) +
  
  # Add bars
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  
  # Add text at the top
  geom_text(aes(label = humidity_perc), vjust = -0.3) +
  
  # Setting Y axis
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Relative humidity (%)", breaks = seq(0, 70, 10), 
                     limits = c(0, 73), expand = c(0, 0), minor_breaks = NULL) +
  
  # Setting fill colours
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray80", "dodgerblue2")) +
  
  # Removing (unnecessary) xlab
  xlab(label = NULL) +
  
  # Changing theme 
  theme_bw() +
  
  # Moving legend to the top
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  
  # Changing title of legend
  labs(fill = "Top 3")
```

Of course, it works for any set of humidity values that you define.

[image]